# The acknowledgement section should appear odd numbered pages

Tags: books

I m using book class. I have acknowledgement page. It appears on even numbered page. I want this to appear on odd numbered page
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Add the command `\cleardoublepage` just before the section ... Also take care that your class is loaded with `twocolumn` option or at least without `onecolumn`

Comment: It worked! Thanks